# How can i access all marker on my GoogleMap-Object (android maps v2) and set them (in)visible?

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, android-maps-v2

i am currently trying to implement an ActionBar-Button that on usage sets all my markers on my GoogleMap-object visible or invisible. My problem is that i don't know how i can get a reference to all my markers once they have been created and are shown on my map. Im looking for a solution where i stash all my marker-objects into an array, that i can access in other parts of my code aswell. is this approach reasonable?

here is what i am thinking of:

```
 private Marker[] mMarkerArray = null;
 for (int i = 0; i < MainActivity.customers.size(); i++) {

     LatLng location = new LatLng(mData.lat, mData.lng);

     Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location)
                          .title(mData.title)
                          .snippet(mData.snippet));
     mMarkerArray.add(marker);                      
   }
```

and set all my markers invisible on within another method:

```
for (int i = 0;  i < mMarkerArray.length;; i++) {
    mMarkerArray[i].setVisible(false);
}
```

it refuses to add the markers to a Marker[]-array. how can i achieve it?

mMarkerArray.add(marker) doesnt work

Answer (score 17, accepted):

i figured out an answer that also regards my customerList having customers without coordinates --> (0,0;0,0). inspired by [this blog.](http://discgolfsoftware.wordpress.com/2012/12/06/hiding-and-showing-on-screen-markers-with-google-maps-android-api-v2/)

**initialize ArrayList:**

```
private ArrayList<Marker> mMarkerArray = new ArrayList<Marker>();
```

**add marker to my map and to the mMarkerArray:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < MainActivity.customers.size(); i++) {
        Customer customer = MainActivity.customers.get(i);
        if (customer.getLon() != 0.0) {
            if (!customer.isProspect()) {
                Data mData= new Data(customer.getLat(),customer.getLon(),customer.getName(),
                        customer.getOrt());

                LatLng location = new LatLng(mData.lat, mData.lng);

                Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location)
                          .title(mData.title)
                          .snippet(mData.snippet));

                mMarkerArray.add(marker); 
}}}
```

**set all markers not-visible**

```
for (Marker marker : mMarkerArray) {
    marker.setVisible(false);
    //marker.remove(); <-- works too!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can keep a `Collection` of [`OverlayItem`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/reference/com/google/android/maps/OverlayItem) within your `Activity` or `Fragment` and then call `MapView.getOverlays().clear()` to make them "invisible" and then add them back to make them visible again.  Call `MapView.invalidate()` after each action to cause the map to be repainted.

Comment: i thought this was just valid for maps v1.  im currently trying to port an app from v1 to v2.

Comment: oh, sorry about that, my android mapview app is still v1, I didn't realize this changed.

Comment: np, btw my v1-version is doing it the OverlayItem-way. but i dont figure how to adapt it for v2 as there is no MapView anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
private Marker[] mMarkerArray = null;
```

with

```
private List<Marker> mMarkerArray = new ArrayList<Marker>();
```

and you should be fine.

If you use [Android Maps Extensions](http://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/), you can simply iterate over all markers using

```
for (Marker marker : googleMap.getMarkers()) {
    marker.setVisible(false);
}
```

without having your own `List` of all `Marker`s.

Comment: thx. my major-problem was that i didnt figure that there were data-sets in the database that had coordinates with 0,0 values and that my HashMAp-attempt tried to get the wrong markers (not the ones WITH coordinates)

Comment: This seems reasonable and looks the most promising, but I can't find the `getMarkers()` method (I'm using Kotlin, which seems to hide getters sometimes??).  Any suggestions?

Comment: googleMap doesn't have getMarkers()