# Google Maps v2 - Get the object related to a marker

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm developing an app that dinamically add markers to a google map. Every marker is generated from and is related to a custom Map object through an **SparseArray**. This is the method that I'm using to relate the markers with the Map objects, add the markers to the map and set the MarkerCliclListener:

```
    /**
     * @author Flagg327
     * @param _map: Array List with Map objects
     */
    public void addMarkers(final ArrayList<Map> _map){
        markerMap = new SparseArray<Marker>();

        for(Map obj : _map) {
            markerMap.put(obj.getId(), map.addMarker(getMarkerForObject(obj)));
        }

        // Bound map to markers
        LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
        for (int cont = 0; cont < _map.size(); cont++) {
            MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(markerMap.get(cont).getPosition());
            builder.include(marker.getPosition());
        }

        // Bound map to markers
        LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();      
        int padding = dpToPx(80);       
        CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);
        map.animateCamera(cu);

        map.setOnMarkerClickListener(markerClickListener);

    }



    /**
     * 
     * @param obj: Map object that contains marker's latitude and longitude
     * @return
     */
    public MarkerOptions getMarkerForObject(Map obj){
        return new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(obj.lat, obj.lng));
    }
```

The **problem** is that **I need to get a reference of the Map object related to a marker when I click on them** in order to get all the data that contains this specific Map object. Something like this:

```
    /**
     * Marker click listener
     */
    private OnMarkerClickListener markerClickListener = new OnMarkerClickListener() {       
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            // TODO Get reference to the Map Object related to *marker*
            return false;
        }
    };
```

Thank you very much for your time. Sorry for my English (I'm trying to rid of Google Translate xD).

Comment: try to follow this , i think it will helpfull for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18126396/how-can-i-access-all-marker-on-my-googlemap-object-android-maps-v2-and-set-the

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you should change your SparseArray so that it holds the marker as the key. And also instead of the id, simply store the entire map object.

```
for (Map obj : _map) {
    Marker marker = getMarkerForObject(obj));
    map.addMarker(marker);
    markerMap.put(marker, obj);
}
```

Now when you want to get the Map object, simply do

```
private OnMarkerClickListener markerClickListener = new OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            mapObj = markerMap.get(marker);
            return false;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Thank you. That is not the problem, it's done with the SparseArray, in the addMarkers() method. Now i need to get a reference of the Map object linked to a marker.

Comment: Understood, am sorry. Please check my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. I had to change a litle bit your code to adapt it to my needs, but the idea is in there. It helps a lot. Checked as right answer. Thank you.